# Get Value of Html Input Inside TemplateField of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the following example, I am unable to get the value of the tel input "Contract".  I do not have any issues with the DropDownList.

aspx Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="Serial,Model" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" Width="50%" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="-1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Serial" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model"/>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="Status" CssClass="dropdownlist" runat="server" onfocus="setSelectedRow(this)" DataValueField="Status" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>' onChange="statusChange(this)">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="RENT READY">Rent Ready</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="ON RENT">On Rent</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="OOS">Out of Service</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>                               
                            <input type="tel" id="Contract" onfocus="setSelectedRow(this)" value= '<%# Eval("Contract") %>' placeholder="Contract #" class='<%# (string)Eval("Status") == "ON RENT" ? "textBox" : "textBoxHidden" %>'></input>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Rendered HTML:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsValid) return;
   foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
   {
      string Serial = row.Cells[0].Text;
      string Model = row.Cells[1].Text;
      string Status = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("Status")).SelectedValue;
      string Contract =  Any one of the below attempts...

      Sql stored procedure integrating the data back to the server...
   }
}

 string Contract = ((HtmlInputControl)row.FindControl("Contract")).Value;

 string Contract = ((HtmlInputText)row.FindControl("Contract")).Value;

 string Contract = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Contract")).Text;
```

All throw Object Reference Not Set to Instance of Object exception.

Comment: are you trying to grab the value on page load, rowdatabound, row updating, etc?

Comment: Button Click.  I am doing a foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

Comment: can you then post the rest of the code for this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your input like this : add a `runat="server"` attribute

use `type = "text"` in the `aspx` file

```
 <input type="text" runat="server" id="Contract" onfocus="setSelectedRow(this)" value= '<%#   
     Eval("Contract") %>' placeholder="Contract #" class='<%# (string)Eval("Status") == "ON  
     RENT" ? "textBox" : "textBoxHidden" %>' ></input>
```

then change it to `type = "tel"` in the code behind when GridRows were created in the  `OnRowCreated` event like this

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            ((HtmlInputText)(e.Row.FindControl("Contract")))
                .Attributes.Add("type", "tel");
    }
```

to retrive the input value use this

```
string Contract = ((HtmlInputText)row.FindControl("Contract")).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically used the "tel" input to bring up the numeric keypad on mobile devices.  Kind of important it do that as the site is exclusively used on tablets.

Comment: Does it compile with the `tel` type?

Comment: Yes.  I included the rendered HTML in the OP, although it is a tad small.

Comment: No.  Now I get "Parser Error Message: 'tel' is not a valid type for an input tag."  I guess there currently isn't a server side answer to new HTML5 input types.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add `runat="server"` to access html input control at
   server side
2. The `value` attribute has no `=` sign and is empty in rendered html
3. There is no ending tag `/` in rendered html

Rendered input tag:

```
<input type="tel" id="Contract" onfocus="setSelectedRow(this)" value placeholder="Contract #" class="textBoxHidden">
```

You need something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Contract" runat="server" onfocus="setSelectedRow(this)" value='<%# (string)Eval("Contract") == "" ? "" : Eval("Contract") %>' placeholder="Contract #" class='<%# (string)Eval("Status") == "ON RENT" ? "textBox" : "textBoxHidden" %>' />
```

If `value` attribute still misses `=` sign in rendered html then try setting its value to some dummy tel.

```
value='<%# (string)Eval("Contract") == "" ? "0" : Eval("Contract") %>'
```